# Is duplicating state of props the only way to go in React.js?

Tags: state, reactjs

Take a look at the source code given below. It models a form that is composed out of two WHOIS components and a radio button group. The radio button determines the WHOIS component that is *selected*. Once the selected WHOIS component is valid the form should be submittable and emit the data of the selected WHOIS.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var Publish = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            type: 'intern',
            intern: {
                domain: '',
                valid: false
            },
            extern: {
                domain: '',
                valid: false
            }
        };
    },
    updateWhois: function(type, domain, state) {
        var newState = {};
        newState[type] = {
            domain: domain,
            valid: state === 'free'
        };
        this.setState(newState);
    },
    switchTo: function(type) {
        this.setState({
            type: type
        });
    },
    isValid: function() {
        var type = this.state.type;
        var typeState = this.state[type];
        return typeState.valid;
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <form className="publish">
                <div>
                    <input name="publish-type" type="radio" checked={this.state.type === 'intern'} onChange={this.switchTo.bind(this, 'intern')} />
                    <Whois onFocus={this.switchTo.bind(this, 'intern')} onChange={this.updateWhois.bind(this, 'intern')} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input name="publish-type" type="radio" checked={this.state.type === 'extern'} onChange={this.switchTo.bind(this, 'extern')} />
                    <Whois onFocus={this.switchTo.bind(this, 'extern')} onChange={this.updateWhois.bind(this, 'extern')} />
                </div>
                <input type="submit" disabled={!this.isValid()} />
            </form>
        );
    }
});
```

This code works perfectly. However I feel I am duplicating the state of the child components. How could I improve this example? Upon submit I would rather query the `Whois` component directly (for example an `.getDomain` method), but I have not clue **if** and how I should do so in ReactJs.

Comment: If you're looking for the state of the form when it is submitted, add a callback for `onSubmit` on the form element and inspect the submitted form at that point for its values. There's no need to inspect the DOM: the form element will be `event.target` in the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel as though there's nothing directly wrong with your example here, as there are different paradigms you can use when writing ReactJS components. If you do want to read from a rendered component, look at the methods in [more about refs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html). Adding a ref property to your whois like so:

```
<Whois onFocus={this.switchTo.bind(this, 'intern')} onChange={this.updateWhois.bind(this, 'intern')} ref="whoIs1" />

this.refs.whoIs1.getDOMNode();
```

would make it possible to look at the component after it has been rendered into the DOM. Using the `event` argument inside a handler for your onChange method would also be a good option, as you can query the component's state out of the properties on `event`.

Comment: Allright. 

So I guess I can drop the `domain` from my state. I can query that using a function on the `Whois` component on submit. 

However the `valid` state I still need. From what I can understand I should not query the `refs` of a component during rendering.